# Paginate FlowDocument (to FixedDocument) with distinct margins for each page

Tags: wpf, pagination, document

I used a `DocumentPaginator` to transform a `FlowDocument` to `FixedDocument`, but the problem is for each page has distinct margins (First, Even and Odd) and distinct page size too (First and Others).

In these articles below, is created a wrapper for the `DocumentPaginator`, works when the margins/page size are equals for all pages:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fyuan/archive/2007/03/10/convert-xaml-flow-document-to-xps-with-style-multiple-page-page-size-header-margin.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31834/FlowDocument-pagination-with-repeating-page-header

I've tried to change the PageSize property (inner `DocumentPaginator`) and PageWidth/PageHeight (`FlowDocument`) in the `GetPage` method, but without success.

Any idea how I can do this?

Thanks!